# How to merge two stored procedures into one method and return one result?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

Here in the code I'm trying to get all data from SQL Server and the method is used to list an users with their rolls in grid form. My question here is how to call/merge two stored procedures and return one result and am I in right way ? If not please explain it and show me the right way so I can learn it how to do it in future. Thanks.

```
public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetAllUsers()
{
    try
    {
        List<ApplicationUser> userList = new List<ApplicationUser>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UsersReadAll", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("sp_GetUserRolls", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ApplicationUser apUser = new ApplicationUser();

                apUser.Id = Convert.ToString(reader["Id"]);
                apUser.UserName = reader["Username"].ToString();
                apUser.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                apUser.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                apUser.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();

                userList.Add(apUser);
            }

            con.Close();
        }

        return userList;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to loop twice. right now you are just reading data for "cmd" and you are doing nothing about cmd2. Do you want unique id result on your userList ? Note : you didn't wrote "cmd2.CommandType = ..." but cmd.CommandType, probably a miss copy/paste :D

Comment: Okay I'll loop it a second time for cmd2 parameter to get the usersRolls, but in the end how I'll return one result with usersList data and usersRolls data so i can List it in grid ? Can you show me an example ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work (i'm considering you want unique id)

```
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetAllUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            ApplicationUser apUser;
            List<ApplicationUser> userList = new List<ApplicationUser>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UsersReadAll", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("sp_GetUserRolls", con);
                cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    apUser = new ApplicationUser();
                    apUser.Id = Convert.ToString(reader["Id"]);
                    apUser.UserName = reader["Username"].ToString();
                    apUser.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    apUser.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    apUser.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
                    userList.Add(apUser);
                }

                // You can refactor this code in another method for don't have to write it both
                reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    apUser = new ApplicationUser();
                    apUser.Id = Convert.ToString(reader["Id"]);

                    // If id doesn't exists, we can continue and add the item 
                    if(!userList.Exists(o=>o.Id==apUser.Id))
                    {
                        apUser.UserName = reader["Username"].ToString();
                        apUser.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                        apUser.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                        apUser.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
                        userList.Add(apUser);
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }

            return userList;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Actually it's like if you had not try / catch
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I just show you the way, i didn't optimised the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can call two stored procedures for one shot and then use Data `SqlDataReader.NextResult()` to read another result set:

```
public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> GetAllUsers()
{
    try
    {
        List<ApplicationUser> userList = new List<ApplicationUser>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"exec sp_UsersReadAll
                                              exec sp_GetUserRolls", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ApplicationUser apUser = new ApplicationUser();

                apUser.Id = Convert.ToString(reader["Id"]);
                apUser.UserName = reader["Username"].ToString();
                apUser.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                apUser.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                apUser.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();

                userList.Add(apUser);
            }

            reader.NextResult();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ApplicationUserRoll apUserRoll = new ApplicationUserRoll();

                apUserRoll.Id = Convert.ToString(reader["Id"]);
                apUserRoll.UserId = reader["UserId"].ToString();

                userList.Single(u => u.Id == apUserRoll.UserId).Rolls.Add(apUserRoll);
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        return userList;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many approaches to do this task. For example -

1. You may create a new procedure which can merge the data for these two procedures and you would have to call one proc only from code.
2. Call one procedure and retain the list of users and pass user ids to seconds procedure to fetch corresponding roles.

Share output of procedures and attributes of `ApplicationUser` class if you are looking for more help.